# Sort array based off parent ID

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I have an array that contains an ID and also a parent_ID. I need to figure out a way to list all objects in the array that share the same parent. The data that generates this array is dynamic and can go up multiple levels deep in some instances.

example array

```
0: {id: "1", parent_id: "0", name: "Greater New York"...}
1: {id: "2", parent_id: "0", name: "Eastern New York"...}
2: {id: "1001", parent_id: "2", name: "Suffolk"...}
3: {id: "1002", parent_id: "2", name: "Nassau"...}
4: {id: "1003", parent_id: "1", name: "Eastern Long Island"...}
5: {id: "1005", parent_id: "1", name: "Bronx"...}
6: {id: "1006", parent_id: "1", name: "Brooklyn"...}
7: {id: "1007", parent_id: "1", name: "Kings Bay"...}
8: {id: "1008", parent_id: "1", name: "Manhattan"...}
9: {id: "1009", parent_id: "1046", name: "Mid-Hudson"...}
10: {id: "1014", parent_id: "1", name: "Westchester"...}
11: {id: "1015", parent_id: "2", name: "Metro"...}
12: {id: "1016", parent_id: "2", name: "Queens"...}
13: {id: "1017", parent_id: "2", name: "Western Queens"...}
14: {id: "1045", parent_id: "1", name: "Lower Hudson"...}
15: {id: "1046", parent_id: "0", name: "North Hudson"...}
16: {id: "1047", parent_id: "1046", name: "Albany"...}
17: {id: "1048", parent_id: "1046", name: "Berkshire County"...}
18: {id: "1049", parent_id: "1046", name: "Mohawk River"...}
19: {id: "1050", parent_id: "1046", name: "Southern Adirondack"...}
20: {id: "1051", parent_id: "1046", name: "Green Mountain"...}
```

Right now i have my JSX returning checkboxes in the order that is put out from the array.

```
{areas.map(area => (
 <div className="col-12 mb-2" key={area.id}>
  <input data-layout={area.type} type="checkbox" value={area.id} 
   onChange={props.onChange}/>
  <label className="ml-3 mb-0">{area.name}</label>
 </div>
))}
```

what i need to do is match the the parent_id to the id and group them all together,
so all with `parent_id: 0` will be top level, then everything will fall under that.

```
Greater New York
  Eastern Long Island
  Bronx
  Brooklyn
  Kings Bay
  Manhattan
  Westchester
  Lower Hudson
Eastern New York
  Suffolk
  Nassau
  Metro
  Queens
  Western Queens
North Hudson
  Mid Hudson
  Albany
  Berkshire County
  Mohawk River
  Southern Adarondack
  Green Mountain
```

Any help formulating this logic would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: All i can find to filter is

```
{areas.filter(area => area.id === 
  area.parent_id).map(filteredArea => (
    <li>{filteredArea}</li>
))}
```

I've played with multiple variations of this, including making a separate array for the parent ID's.

Comment: What have you tried? You need to show some attempt

Comment: so everything i have found points me to the filter() 
{areas.filter(area => area.id === area.parent_id).map(filteredArea => (
       <li>{filteredArea.name}</li>
     ))}

this returns undefined.

Everything else I have been doing is just pulling apart the array and trying to figure out the logic.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to group objects by `parent_id`, below code will be able to help.

```js
let groupBy = (array, key) => {
    return array.reduce((result, obj) => {
       (result[obj[key]] = result[obj[key]] || []).push(obj);
       return result;
    }, {});
 };

 groupBy(data,'parent_id');
```

Output :

```json
{
  '0': [
    { id: '1', parent_id: '0', name: 'Greater New York' },
    { id: '2', parent_id: '0', name: 'Eastern New York' },
    { id: '1046', parent_id: '0', name: 'North Hudson' }
  ],
  '1': [
    { id: '1003', parent_id: '1', name: 'Eastern Long Island' },
    { id: '1005', parent_id: '1', name: 'Bronx' },
    { id: '1006', parent_id: '1', name: 'Brooklyn' },
    { id: '1007', parent_id: '1', name: 'Kings Bay' },
    { id: '1008', parent_id: '1', name: 'Manhattan' },
    { id: '1014', parent_id: '1', name: 'Westchester' },
    { id: '1045', parent_id: '1', name: 'Lower Hudson' }
  ],
  '2': [
    { id: '1001', parent_id: '2', name: 'Suffolk' },
    { id: '1002', parent_id: '2', name: 'Nassau' },
    { id: '1015', parent_id: '2', name: 'Metro' },
    { id: '1016', parent_id: '2', name: 'Queens' },
    { id: '1017', parent_id: '2', name: 'Western Queens' }
  ],
  '1046': [
    { id: '1009', parent_id: '1046', name: 'Mid-Hudson' },
    { id: '1047', parent_id: '1046', name: 'Albany' },
    { id: '1048', parent_id: '1046', name: 'Berkshire County' },
    { id: '1049', parent_id: '1046', name: 'Mohawk River' },
    { id: '1050', parent_id: '1046', name: 'Southern Adirondack' },
    { id: '1051', parent_id: '1046', name: 'Green Mountain' }
  ]
}
```

You can then use this list to generate your `<li>` elements

Comment: this solves half of the problem. now for each with parent_id 0, i need to place all with parent_id == this.id. I will need to play with this for a while to get it. Thanks for the bump in the right direction. Will update shortly.